# Youtube Data API v3 uploading videos to a shared channel

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

The following Python script uploads a mp4 file to a Youtube channel through the Youtube Data API v3. The account gets identified with OAuth2 and uses a token as well as a refresh token. It works fine so far, so a user can upload a video into his own Youtube channel.

But I would like to rewrite the script so that the logged in user uploads the mp4 file not to his own Youtube channel, but instead to a channel where he has also access to. Is that even possible with the Youtube Data API v3?

```py
creds = Credentials(
    token=token, 
    refresh_token=refresh_token, 
    client_id=client_id, 
    client_secret=client_secret, 
    token_uri="https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube']
)
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=creds)
body=dict(
    snippet=dict(
        title=title,
        description=description,
        tags=["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
        categoryId=str(category)
    ),
    status=dict(
        privacyStatus="private"
    )
)
media = MediaIoBaseUpload(
    io.BytesIO(file), 
    mimetype='video/mp4', 
    chunksize=-1, 
    resumable=True
)

try:
    youtube.videos().insert(
        part=",".join(body.keys()),
        body=body,
        media_body=media,
    ).execute()
except HttpError as error:
    print(F'An error occured: {error}')
```